# How can we increase java heap size in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Can anyone please help me increasing java heap size in neo4j. Please explain required instructions step by step as I am newbie in neo4j. I am not able to understand answers present in other threads and also what's written there in neo4j documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a newbie you don't need to increase java heap size , you can work with the default values ...
In the official documentation [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/) it is well explained ...
Check also here [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/memory-configuration/#heap-sizing)

What you need to do in general is:

1. Stop the neo4j service( $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j stop )
2. Find the $NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf file in your system and set this values:

   ```
   Property Name                     Meaning
   dbms.memory.heap.initial_size     initial heap size (in MB)
   dbms.memory.heap.max_size         maximum heap size (in MB)
   ```
3. Start the neo4j service ( $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j start )

Generally it very depends how much RAM your server has , but without knowing your workload and database size I would recommend following parameters that most probably will be correct for any type of load:

```
 RAM      heap 
 16GB      6GB
 32GB     10GB
 64GB     24GB
128GB     31GB
```

You could execute also the neo4j-admin command that can suggest suitable values based on your current database and RAM size:

```
  $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-admin memrec
```

Note that beside the heap size , there is one more parameter that affect  performance depending on database size and this is the:

```
dbms.memory.pagecache.size
```

You can also set it manually in the neo4j.conf